# EXCEL Javascript API: NamedItem losts it's reference after copying source workbook into current workbook via insertWorksheetsFromBase64

Tags: excel, office-addins, react-typescript, excel-addins, javascript-api-for-office

## Current Behavior:

After loading template.xlsx file to current workbook via insertWorksheetsFromBase64:

```
const startIndex = sheetsString?.indexOf("base64,");
const externalWorkbook: string = sheetsString ? sheetsString.substring(startIndex ? startIndex + 7 : 7) : "";
const workbook = context.workbook;

workbook.insertWorksheetsFromBase64(externalWorkbook);
```

the namedItem from the source workbook is not correctly referenced. Excel returns it's formula as so =#REF!$[Location] (see picture below). After that I try to load another workbook. The namedItem from the old workbook is still accessible in this new workbook

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jn0sd.png)

## Expected Behavior

- Excel recognizes the reference defined in the template.xlsx file and returns =Table1!$[Location] in the formula (see picture below).
- namedItem should only be accessible/visible for that current workbook. After loading a new workbook, the namedItem should not be loaded.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QF7gb.png)

## Environment

Platform [PC desktop, Mac, iOS, Office Online]: Mac desktop
Host [Excel, Word, PowerPoint, etc.]: Excel
Office version number: Excel for Mac version 16.75.2 (23071901)
Operating System: MacOS
Browser (if using Office Online): N/A